# Preview Azure Analytics

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I enabled Analytics Views under Preview Features, but I do not see Analytics View in my project.
I closed the web browser and relaunched - nothing
I rebooted the laptop - nothing

Any other ideas?

### Thanks

Comment: Can you show where you expect to get this view?

Comment: @Winston Snyder. Is there any update about this ticket? Feel free to let me know if the suggestions below could help you.

Answer (score 1):

For the Analytics Views, when you enable the Analytics Views in Preview Feature.

You can see the Analytics Views in the Overview tab.

[image]

In Analytics Views, you can custom the Analytics views.

Then you can use this Analytics views in PowerBI.

For more detailed info, you could refer to this doc: [What are Analytics views?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/powerbi/what-are-analytics-views?view=azure-devops)

Note: If Boards is disabled, then Analytics views will also be disabled and all widgets associated with work item tracking won't appear in the widget catalog and will become disabled.